# Is there any way to implement a smooth customer migration from 1GMP to 2GMP?

Tags: migration, second-generation-packaging, 2gmp

I build 2GMP for client who has many customers installed their previous 1GMP version of the package.

I couldn't figure out how to make this process smooth enough with simple upgrade so they have to make call with every customer and help them to backup any package dependencies, uninstall the 1GMP version, install the 2GMP version and restore any dependencies they had.

This is very tedious and unpleasant process and some customers were not quite happy to follow this way.

Is there any way to implement a smooth customer migration from 1GMP to 2GMP?

I tried to find some undocumented feature on this but failed. I have even tried to set `ancestorId` property of `sfdx-project.json` to the 1GMP package version like this

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "package": "Smooth migration to 2GMP trial",
            "versionName": "ver 0.0",
            "versionNumber": "0.0.0.NEXT",
            "ancestorId": "04t2E000003e2W2"
        }
    ],
    "name": "2gmp-migrate",
    "namespace": "fforce",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "52.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "Smooth migration to 2GMP trial": "0Ho1n000000PAw0CAG"
    }
}
```

but I have received the following error:

```
ERROR running force:package:version:create:  The Subscriber Package Version Id 04t2E000003e2W2 is invalid, as a corresponding Package Version Id was not found 

Try this: 
It`s possible that this package was created on a different Dev Hub. Authenticate to the Dev Hub org that owns the package, and reference that Dev Hub when running the command.
```

It is clear that 1GMP doesn't belong to a different dev hub since 1GMP do not connect to devhub. I hoped that if I use the same namespace, Salesforce will allow me to create a 2GMP package version which would inherit my 1GMP package version, but apparently there is no undocumented way to do that. Is there any other possible workarounds or ideas?

Answer (score 5):

> I build 2GMP for client who has many customers installed their previous 1GMP version of the package.

Respectfully, you and your client have made a strategic error here. It would've been far cheaper and guaranteed a better customer experience if you'd created a new 1GMP version.

> Is there any way to implement a smooth customer migration from 1GMP to 2GMP?

Unless and until 1GP->2GP migration is released by Salesforce, for which Ι believe there is not currently a public release commitment, there is no smooth migration path possible.

> I hoped that if I use the same namespace, Salesforce will allow me to create a 2GMP package version which would inherit my 1GMP package version

You can create a 2GP package with the same namespace as the 1GP, but those packages are totally independent of one another and there is no upgrade path between them.

Comment: They say this is eventually coming, but it's hard to wait for it. We needed it like last year.

Comment: Making a new 1GMP version for old package was not an option, since that would block installation of another package which we build from scratch with the same namespace. If they kept releasing 1GMP version, client's customers wouldn't have been able to install both packages.

Comment: We could build a new package from scratch as 1GMP or 2GMP with a different namespace, but I didn't want to suggest clients to use old technologies for a new package, so I didn't want to suggest 1GMP for a brand new package; also it wouldn't make sense to register another namespace just for a new package if they already own one and wanted to keep that namespace

Comment: Yes, but _there is no 1GP->2GP migration available_, so those decisions about package architecture have directly harmed existing customers. It sounds like the right decision was to create a new namespace, but granted I don't have all the information.

Comment: FYI: Winter '22 actually has a mention of this conversion being in [developer preview](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sfdx_packaging_ext_dev_preview.htm&type=5&release=234).